# Is there a way to find out the cause of a css rule that webkit shows an error for?

Tags: css, webkit

Sometimes I'll have a css rule that webkit doesn't render, but doesn't totally ignore either.

A little yellow error triangle will show in the inspector, and the rule will be crossed out.

Is there any way to find out *what* about the rule is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the tooltip of the little yellow triangle.